# App Icon with transparent background doesn't appear transparent on device

Tags: android, icons

I created an app icon on `GIMP` with transparent background and double checked the transparency by pasting the icon image on colored pages in word editors. I went ahead and used the icon image and created the apk file. However, after installation, the icon background is not transparent on the device(LG Optimus S) screen. Has anyone ever had this issue? Thanks in advance for any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: What is the format of your image ?

Comment: please post some code, what does your layout look like?

Comment: @rockeye The Image is a 24-bit PNG type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, but I used Paint.NET on Windows.

When saving the image, I used the Auto-Detect setting for PNGs, but changing this to 32-bit solved my problem.

I tried saving my image as a 24-bit PNG too but this produced the white background and wasnt transparent.

Maybe try 32-bit PNG....

(my trials were done by inserting image into PowerPoint slide which had coloured background)

Comment: I just re-created the Project in Eclipse and the 24-bit image now works with all its transparency. I have no idea what just happened. Thanks for suggesting a fix though.

Comment: Doing a clean on the project in Eclipse would have probably fixed your problem. I was also having the same problem. I had changed my images but still the old images would appear on the phone. This option can be found in: Project->Clean...

Comment: @Farish That's interesting... can't remember if I tried that. Possibly not as I might not have thought it would have done anything to the images.